# Rotational Equilibrium Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, torque, equilibrium

[image: Static Equilibrium]
The question is as follows:
One end of a uniform 4.0-m rod, whose weight is w, is supported by a cable that makes an angle of 37° with the horizontal. The other end of the bar rests against a wall where it is held by friction ($μ_s$ = 0.50).
A weight w (equal to the weight of the rod) is now hung somewhere on the rod (at a distance x from the wall) so that the system is just in translational and rotational equilibrium. Find x. 
But the answer I got was negative which didn't make sense. Can someone help me?

My work so far:

$\Sigma \mathbf F_x = 0 \rightarrow -T\cos\theta + N_{wall} =0$

$\Sigma \mathbf F_y = 0 \rightarrow -mg -mg +f_s + T\sin\theta =0$

$\Sigma \mathbf \tau = 0 \rightarrow -mgx -2mg +T\sin\theta =0$ choosing the wall-rod point as the axis of rotation.

Substituting $f_s =\mu_s N_{wall}$ and $N_{wall} = T\cos\theta$ into the $F_y$ equation gives:

$-2mg + \mu_s T\cos\theta + T\sin\theta =0$, which when solved for T yields:

$T = \frac{2mg}{\mu_s \cos\theta + \sin\theta}$

Substituting that into the torque equation and solving for x yields

$x = \frac{2\sin\theta}{\mu_s \cos\theta + \sin\theta}-2$...but that's negative!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to multiply $T \sin{\theta}$ by the distance from the wall to the end of the bar in the torque balance.  When you do that, you get an extra factor of 4 in the first term for the expression for x, $x = \frac{8\sin{\theta}}{\mu_s \cos{\theta} + \sin{\theta}} - 2$, which is positive.

(PS: I didn't check your math, I just added the factor of 4, so I can't vouch for the algebra.)